# Service-now, where to begin?

Tags: servicenow

I'm working as a Desktop Support Specialists at Day & Zimmerman. Along desktop support I code in a free time.

I would like to become a certified Service-Now Admin.

What are good materials to start learning about Service-Now?

I understand why companies are using Service-Now, how it is used, but I would like to learn **how to configure it**, configure workflows for Service Catalog requests, create groups to filter tickets between different IT teams, and create UI policies and scripts.

I have a strong JavaScript knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: Answers provided are not spam. Answers are very helpful, I am already using the resources provided in answers. Now I know how to modify Service-Now procedures. The fact that resources that were provided in answers helped me to get here where I am, justifies the importance of answers, and ultimately the quality of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I see. Your Q looked like a low quality question at first sigth. Sorry for that.

Comment: I'm a service-now developer and would be happy to answer any questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Start reading from [Service Now Wiki](http://wiki.service-now.com).Start from get "Get Started".What ever you learn you can practice on demo instances provided by Service Now "**https://demo.service-now.com**" . In the this link add "**001**" to "**023**" after "**demo**"

   It's simple o understand and start from the above.

2.Once you are familiar with the basics then you can go ahead with **servicenowguru.com**.It has a lot of useful code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

You might already be in the best place to get started - ask some questions here on StackOverflow as there is a growing community of customers, partners and employees happy to help.

The ServiceNow Wiki is the traditional place to start. On the ServiceNow Community there are Learning Center resources.

On Google+ there is another growing community of friendly people to help you get up to speed.[0]. The #ServiceNow Twitter hashtag is very active too.

Lastly - find out how to connect with your local ServiceNow User Group (SNUG)[1]. You can meet other users in your area.

Good luck!

[0] https://plus.google.com/communities/115940571564789841375

[1] http://community.servicenow.com/og

Answer (score 0):

I took two classes that are offered by Service-Now, one is the admin class which is the recommended place to start and then a scripting class. Both were great classes...

More info:
http://www.servicenow.com/training.do

Answer (score 0):

A good place where to check for what others have done to achieve the certification is the following LinkedIn group:
http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=4103160

Also, ServiceNowGuru has a very good list of skills you should master (pursuing a certification or not):
http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=4103160